# Maple: How to turn a set of vectors into a matrix?

Tags: math-software, computer-algebra-systems, maple

In Maple the command [NullSpace](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=LinearAlgebra/NullSpace) turns a given matrix into a set of vectors -- a basis for its null space. This is precisely what it should in a mathematical sense. However, for computations using the obtained basis, it would be more convenient to have as output a matrix whose columns are the basis vectors.

I'm having a hard time *converting a set of vectors into a matrix whose columns are the given vectors*. The order doesn't matter (of course). Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite easy:

```
kern := NullSpace(A)    
Test := Matrix(convert(kern, list))
```

should perfectly do the job for you (note that it also depends on your exact version of Maple)